# Intuition for Hotelling's T^2 Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, intuition, multivariate-regression, hotelling-t2

I have been learning about Hotelling's $T^2$ test from *Multivariate Statistics: Old School*. The test is given by $T^2 = \nu\cdot\text{trace}(\bf{W}^{-1}\bf{B})$. The author shows that in the case of multivariate regression, $\bf{W}$ is the RSS matrix for the full model and $\bf{W} + \bf{B}$ is the the RSS matrix for the reduced model.

We would want to reject the full model when the RSS matrix for the full model doesn't improve very much compared to the reduced model. To quantify how much the model improves, first we would want to compare the diagonal entries in each matrix, to see if they go down significantly for the full model.

For the off diagonal entries, I would assume that lower values are generally better. For example, if I am given two models, A and B, both of which have the same diagonal entries in the RSS matrix, but model A has large off diagonal entries, while model B has zeros in the off diagonal entries, I would prefer model B. This is because with model A, since the off diagonal entires are large, this means that for each observation, if the predicted response for the first column is too large, then the predictions for the other columns will tend to be large too, and likewise for if the predicted response is too small. Thus, the predictions are less "fair" among the observations for model A than for model B.

Next, I tried to test whether my own intuition matches the computation performed in the test. I used the "histamine" data set from package "msos" and performed a multivariate regression. In the histamine data set, there are 16 observations. The first 4 correspond to group 1, the next 4 correspond to group 2, and so on. I encoded group 1 as [1,0,0,0], group 2 as [1,1,0,0], group 3 as [1,0,1,0], and group 4 as [1,0,0,1].

I obtained the following $\bf{W}$ matrix:
[image: W]

The inverse is:
[image: W^-1]

For the reduced model, I got rid of the last column of $X$. So, the test would be whether or not the effect of the last group is the same as the effect of the first group. This resulted in a $\bf{B}$ matrix as follows:

[image: B]

The diagonal entries of $\bf{W}^{-1}$ make sense to me. Kind of. It makes sense that they are all positive, since they are multiplied by the diagonal entires of the $\bf{B}$ matrix, which means larger diagonal entries of $\bf{B}$ results in a larger $T^2$ value. However, I don't understand the different sizes of each of the diagonal entries. I believe it should represent some kind of weighting for each diagonal entry of $\bf{B}$, but I'm not sure how specifically.

On the other hand, the off diagonal entries of $\bf{W}^{-1}$ don't make any sense to me. As mentioned above, I feel that smaller off diagonal entries are preferred. But the off diagonal entries of $\bf{W}^{-1}$ are sometimes positive and sometimes negative, which means that if the full model reduces all of the off diagonal entries, sometimes this is penalized, and sometimes this is rewarded, according to the $T^2$ test.

Therefore, my questions are:

1. Is my intuition for smaller off diagonal entries being better valid?
2. If this intuition is valid, why do we multiply $\bf{B}$ by $\bf{W}^{-1}$, when it seems to sometimes penalize smaller off diagonal entries? (That is, it is possible for the full model to reduce the off diagonal entries, and yet result in a smaller $T^2$ value.)
3. Do any of the other tests (e.g. Wilk's, Pillai's) align with my intuition for what constitutes a good test better?